# PySpark: Can't do column operations with datetime years = 0001

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have data where some timestamps are of the form "0001-mm-dd HH:MM:SS". I'm trying to get the minimum time. In order to get the minimum time, I need to convert to a DoubleType first because the minimum function for PySpark dataframes apparently doesn't work for timestamps. However, for some reason, datetimes hate the year 0001. No matter what I do, I cannot get it to work. Below, I try to use a UDF to manually increase the year by 1, but for some reason, it doesn't register. However, I can use a different column of data that has no 0001 years and change the if statement in the function to a year contained in the data, and I can observe the year changing.

What am I doing wrong?

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
import pyspark.sql.functions as sfunc
import pyspark.sql.types as tp
from pyspark import SparkConf
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

columnname='x'
#columnname='y'
tmpdf.select(columnname).show(5)

def timeyearonecheck(date):
    '''Datetimes breaks down at year = 0001, so bump up the year to 0002'''
    if date.year == 1:
        newdate=date+relativedelta(years=1)
        return newdate
    else:
        return date

def timeConverter(timestamp):
    '''Takes either a TimestampType() or a DateType() and converts it into a 
    float'''
    timetuple=timestamp.timetuple()
    if type(timestamp) == datetime.date:
        timevalue=time.mktime(timetuple)
        return int(timevalue)
    else:
        timevalue=time.mktime(timetuple)+timestamp.microsecond/1000000
        return timevalue

tmptimedf1colname='tmpyeartime'
yearoneudf=sfunc.udf(timeyearonecheck,tp.TimestampType())
tmptimedf1=tmpdf.select(yearoneudf(sfunc.col(columnname)).alias(tmptimedf1colname))
tmptimedf2colname='numbertime'
timeudf=sfunc.udf(timeConverter,tp.DoubleType())
tmptimedf2=tmptimedf1.select(timeudf(sfunc.col(tmptimedf1colname)).alias(tmptimedf2colname))
minimum=tmptimedf2.select(tmptimedf2colname).rdd.min()[0]


+-------------------+
|                  x|
+-------------------+
|0001-01-02 00:00:00|
|0001-01-02 00:00:00|
|0001-01-02 00:00:00|
|0001-01-02 00:00:00|
|0001-01-02 00:00:00|
+-------------------+
only showing top 5 rows

Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-b5725bf01860> in <module>()
 17 timeudf=sfunc.udf(timeConverter,tp.DoubleType())
 18 
tmptimedf2=tmpdf.select(timeudf(sfunc.col(columnname)).
alias(tmptimedf2colname))
---> 19 minimum=tmptimedf2.select(tmptimedf2colname).rdd.min()[0]
 20 print(minimum)
...
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling 
z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 
in stage 43.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.3 in stage 
43.0 (TID 7829, 10.10.12.41, executor 39): 
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
ValueError: year 0 is out of range
```

Even when I just try to look at the output of the first UDF, I get an error, but only when I look at the output, not when I actually calculate it.

```
tmptimedf1.select(tmptimedf1colname).show(5)

Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-5fc942678065> in <module>()
----> 1 tmptimedf1.select(tmptimedf1colname).show(5)
...
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2215.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 
 in stage 44.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 
44.0 (TID 7984, 10.10.12.36, executor 4): 
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call 
last):
...
ValueError: year 0 is out of range
```

What's more, I get the same ValueError talking about year 0 if I do:

```
tmpdf.select(columnname).first()
```

But only if I use the column with years of 0001, not the 'y' column with no 0001 years. The 'y' column works fine.

I don't get why I can show 5 values for tmpdf which include 0001, but I can't pick the first value because it has 0001.

EDIT: As noted below, I'd really like to just convert the years 0001 to year 0002 because PySpark's approxQuantile doesn't work on timestamps, and in general, I won't know the datasets well enough to know what years are acceptable. 0001 is definitely a filler year, but 1970 might be a real year in my data (in the general case for my job).

I've gotten this so far:

```
def tmpfunc(timestamp):
    time=datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    return time

adf=datadf.select(sfunc.col(columnname).cast("string").alias('a'))
newdf = adf.withColumn('b',sfunc.regexp_replace('a', '0001-', '0002-'))
newdf.show(10)
print(newdf.first())
tmpudf=sfunc.udf(tmpfunc,tp.TimestampType())
newnewdf=newdf.select(tmpudf(sfunc.col('b')).alias('c'))
newnewdf.show(10)
print(newnewdf.first())

+-------------------+-------------------+
|                  a|                  b|
+-------------------+-------------------+
|0001-01-02 00:00:00|0002-01-02 00:00:00|
|0001-01-02 00:00:00|0002-01-02 00:00:00|
|0001-01-02 00:00:00|0002-01-02 00:00:00|
|0001-01-02 00:00:00|0002-01-02 00:00:00|
|0001-01-02 00:00:00|0002-01-02 00:00:00|
|2015-10-13 09:56:09|2015-10-13 09:56:09|
|0001-01-02 00:00:00|0002-01-02 00:00:00|
|2013-11-05 21:28:09|2013-11-05 21:28:09|
|1993-12-24 03:52:47|1993-12-24 03:52:47|
|0001-01-02 00:00:00|0002-01-02 00:00:00|
+-------------------+-------------------+
only showing top 10 rows

Row(a='0001-01-02 00:00:00', b='0002-01-02 00:00:00')
+-------------------+
|                  c|
+-------------------+
|0002-01-03 23:56:02|
|0002-01-03 23:56:02|
|0002-01-03 23:56:02|
|0002-01-03 23:56:02|
|0002-01-03 23:56:02|
|2015-10-13 09:56:09|
|0002-01-03 23:56:02|
|2013-11-05 21:28:09|
|1993-12-24 03:52:47|
|0002-01-03 23:56:02|
+-------------------+
only showing top 10 rows

Row(c=datetime.datetime(2, 1, 2, 0, 0))
```

As a user commented below, the days in the "show" are 1 day, 23 hours, 56 minutes, and 2 seconds off. Why, and how do I get rid of that? And then why is my "first" call correct, but is also missing a 0 in what should be (2,1,2,0,0,0)?

Answer (score 1):

> In order to get the minimum time, I need to convert to a DoubleType first because the minimum function for PySpark dataframes apparently doesn't work for timestapms.

It does

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    ["0001-01-02 00:00:00", "0001-01-03 00:00:00"], "string"
).selectExpr("to_timestamp(value) AS x")

min_max_df = df.select(sfunc.min("x"), sfunc.max("x"))
min_max_df.show()
# +-------------------+-------------------+
# |             min(x)|             max(x)|
# +-------------------+-------------------+
# |0001-01-02 00:00:00|0001-01-03 00:00:00|
# +-------------------+-------------------+
```

The failing part is actually conversion to a local value:

```py
>>> min_max_df.first()
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts // 1000000).replace(microsecond=ts % 1000000)
ValueError: year 0 is out of range
```

Epoch timestamp for the minimum is

```py
>>> df.select(sfunc.col("x").cast("long")).first().x
-62135683200
```

Which seems to be shifted 2 days back (Scala code) when converted back to date:

```scala
scala> java.time.Instant.ofEpochSecond(-62135683200L)
res0: java.time.Instant = 0000-12-31T00:00:00Z
```

and as a result is no longer valid in Python.

Assuming `0001` is just a placeholder you could ignore it on parsing:

```py
df.select(sfunc.to_timestamp(
   sfunc.col("x").cast("string"),
   "0001-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").alias("x")
)).select(
    sfunc.min("x"),
    sfunc.max("x")
).first()
# Row(min(x)=datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 2, 1, 0), max(x)=datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 3, 1, 0))
```

You can also just cast the results directly to string:

```py
df.select(sfunc.min("x").cast("string"), sfunc.max("x").cast("string")).first()
# Row(CAST(min(x) AS STRING)='0001-01-02 00:00:00', CAST(max(x) AS STRING)='0001-01-03 00:00:00')
```

Comment: Ah, yes. The problem with the datetime was in a later part of my code not shown where I try to use approxQuantile and get this error: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o3334.approxQuantile. : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Quantile calculation for column x with data type TimestampType is not supported. So I still need to convert the 0001 to something else, preferably 0002 because I'm unfamiliar with the data and don't want to change much. Your second to last code block seems promising, but it doesn't convert to 0002 and nulls out the years != 0001.